# Azure AD for Mac

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

we would like to use Azure AD credentials to sign in Mac machines and we are aware of that could be achieved to use Azure AD credentials to sign in local machines via Azure AD join while it is currently only supported for Windows 10. Hence may I know is there a work around for us to achieve using Azure AD credentials to sign in Mac machines? And we figure out the possible solution that we could create ADDS service in our Azure Active directory, and join the Mac machine to Azure AD Domain Service then use our Azure AD credentials to sign in the Mac Machine. May I know is it possible for Mac machine to join Azure AD Domain Service? and is the whole process workable for us to achieve the requirement? Thanks a lot on any ideas on this issue!!!

Comment: This is not a programming related question.  You should be asking this over at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: You can join Mac OSX to Azure AD DS.This document may help you:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-compatible-software  Additional, there is a guide to Integrate OS X with AD;http://training.apple.com/pdf/Best_Practices_for_Integrating_OS_X_with_Active_Directory.pdf But I didn't test it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> may I know is there a work around for us to achieve using Azure AD
>   credentials to sign in Mac machines?

You cannot join Azure AD with Mac OS X. If this is important to you , you can upvote this in [this Feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16117459-azure-ad-join-mac-os-x).

> May I know is it possible for Mac machine to join Azure AD Domain
>   Service?

it's possible for Mac  to join Azure AD Domain Service.

[One Identity Authentication Services](https://www.quest.com/products/authentication-services/) enables Unix, Linux, and Mac OS X systems to use the access, authentication, and authorization of an organization’s existing Active Directory (AD) infrastructure. Authentication Services now supports Azure Active Directory Domain Services enabling non-Windows resources to utilize the same next-generation platform that your existing SaaS solutions already use.

Also, there is [a guide](http://training.apple.com/pdf/Best_Practices_for_Integrating_OS_X_with_Active_Directory.pdf) to integrate Mac OS X with AD.

Due to that I don't have Mac OS X in my test lab, so I didn't test.

Hope this helps!

Comment: there is no guide, the page says : The page you’re looking for can’t be found.
can you please send the document if you have it.